# Java regex - matching beginning of a string

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex and am having trouble making this work. The following line returns false but I think it should return true.

```
Pattern.matches("^DOI", "DOI 10.1364/OL.36.002946")
```

What I want is to match the first three letters "DOI", regardless of what comes after it. I try to remove the anchor but it still does not match. Can anyone help explain it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^DOI.*", "DOI 10.1364/OL.36.002946"));
```

You want your text to start with DOI and after that you just want any amount of any character `.*`

However as stated in the other responses, `String.startWith` is way better if you are only checking that your string starts with a fixed prefix. Regexp will allow you to do more powerful things though, however it is more painful performance wise (and way more complex code wise).

Comment: Consider that `Pattern.matches` is less efficient than `.startsWith` in this case. If you have only one check, use `.startsWith`.

Comment: Agree, if you only want to check that your string begins with a predefined string you don't need a regexp for that.

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
String yourVar = "DOI dskljdj";
if (yourVar.startsWith("DOI")) { ... }
```

It will check if your String begins with DOI or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best route to go

```
String.startsWith("DOI");
```